# Combine IP filter and cakePHP rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use cakePHP, that uses the following rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

I now need to add an IP filter, that gives a single IP access to a path (and others get 403 Forbidden). I got that to work by writing:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.345\.67\.89$
RewriteRule ^/the-path/ - [F,L]
```

But how can I combine these? The IP filter seems to be ignored if I do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.345\.67\.89$
RewriteRule ^/the-path/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You are better off putting the-path in the webroot folder (which should be the doc root anyway) and, where required,  only editing `app\webroot\.htaccess`.

Comment: I've tried that as well, but I still can't seem to combine the IP stuff with the already existing rules.

Comment: I'm not saying "it'll just work if" - I'm saying you should always use a production install, and irrespective of that should only edit the webroot .htaccess file for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading slash in `RewriteRule` pattern and simplify your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.345\.67\.89$
RewriteRule ^the-path(/.*)?$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still won't work. I only get Forbidden if I exclude the last rule.

Comment: You will get forbidden if IP is NOT `12.345.67.89` check fro Apache logs what IP it is getting.

Comment: I assume it is getting the right one, since I get forbidden if I remove the exclamation mark and the last rule.

Comment: Please don't assume and check Apache access.log to see what exact IP is being detected there.

Comment: @anubhava you... recommend doing that instead of allow deny rules?

Comment: @AD7six allow/deny rules cannot work on a specific URL pattern like `^the-path(/.*)?$`

Comment: I assumed `the-path` existed - your last comment reads as: you can't apply allow/deny to a folder (surely, you don't mean that). @joakimdahlstrom if the-path is a CakePHP route is there a reason you aren't implementing this in your application logic (which would be trivial. not that the rewrite rule logic is difficult)?

Comment: I have checked that the IP is right. But since I'm testing with a negative pattern (!) I wouldn't really need to. I don't really want to have it in the application logic, but maybe I have to..

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom: Rule will force forbidden error for `^the-path(/.*)?$` path for all the IPs except `12.345.67.89` so it is important that Apache see IP as `12.345.67.89`